# calculating location of a mobile phone not by using GPS

Tags: java, java-me

guys i am trying to develop an Java application for calculating the location of user through his Java phone, not by using GPS, that location can be used later for my research in same project, please help me by your current knowledge about this topic for my project, you can mail me the data regarding this at cooshh@gmail.com or just tell me from where should i start this?? thanx in advance .....

Comment: I have the impression your first problem finding localization techniques that are not based on GPS; afterwards you may want to investigate availability of java libraries for implementing those techniques. So, have you already identify a a non-GPS based localization technique?

Comment: You want to find where someone is without him having a GPS ? If this is your question then the answer would be: You can't. Furthermore, you shouldn't need or want to do this (since its illegal in most countries). Usually operators can do this by cell tower triangulation, but they need the allowance of the phone owner.

Comment: @lngo : i currently dont have any data, i am just in the beginning step with an idea
@simeon : it will be useful for the user coz i will provide them with some services according to his location, Off course after the proper validation of user
@marcoS no not yet, its just a beginning

Comment: You wont get any data you need because it is illegal for providers to give them away, and even if this is not so, they'll have sold the right to that data long ago or they are marketing them by themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only four ways to determine the position of a cell phone.

- An internal GPS.  This is the most accurate method.
- WiFi location.  The phone is within the range of the WiFi signal.
- Cell tower triangulation.  As the name implies, 3 or more cell towers in different directions have to be in range of the phone for this to work.
- Cell tower location.  This is the least accurate method, as a phone could be anywhere within the range of the cell tower.

Comment: It might be interesting to know that in some countries not even the police may legally use the cell tower data.

Comment: @Ingo:  True.  I just mentioned what was technically possible.  If you're trying to find earthquake survivors, I'd hope the cell phone companies would be reasonable about using their cell tower data.

Comment: well thanx Gilbert, I am interested in the third way u suggested to do this, but i am not able to think how to implement this, can u suggest some study material for the same?

Comment: @koshh: Sure.  Here's the Wikipedia article on Triangulation, and an article on cell tower triangulation, to get you started.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation  http://searchengineland.com/cell-phone-triangulation-accuracy-is-all-over-the-map-14790

Comment: okay thanks Gilbert, And let me know if you find out anything new related to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

One of my students did this, on a Sony Ericsson in Sweden, by retrieving the cell id. It was not possible to get a list of the locations of all the cell towers (trade secrets! terrorists! national security!), but Google knows surprisingly much, and there was a Google API that actually returned the longitude and latitude of the cell tower.

Comment: i would like to talk with that guy about this in details, can u give me his id  or something?

Comment: If you e-mail me (thomas.padron-mccarthy@oru.se) I'll forward your question and your e-mail address to him (or at least to his last known e-mail address).

Comment: Hi @ThomasPadron-McCarthy, can you please join me in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6137/)  I want to know more about this cell id